# Stubborn Byte Order Mark in cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I know there are a lot of questions on this topic, I've been reading and trying different ideas for hours.

I'm fetching data using the Dropbox api, which works fine, but it's slow.
So I'm moving this fetch to ajax.

The json response has the ever popular invisible question mark appended to the end of the string... after the closing square bracket.

```
.....}]?
```

This makes the json object invalid and none of the regular functions work on invalid json.

It's there when I load the page direct, but goes away when I set autoRender to false. So I got it working.... but, I would like to find this little POS and remove it before it shows up randomly in the future. It took hours to figure out that this was problem because it's invisible!

I can use Notepad++ to eradicate the little beasty, but I can't find it!
I've tried the following...

```
grep -rlI $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' .
```

Total Commander -> go to project's root dir -> find files (alt+f7) -> file types *.* -> Find text "EF BB BF" -> check 'Hex' checkbox -> search

search in project for charset=iso-8859

Tried this hack

```
$response = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $response);
```

I use Netbeans which near as I can tell is worthless for this problem.

Keep in mind, this is Cakephp 2.3, so there are about 3.7 million files that get loaded.

How do you find these things??

Comment: Have you searched your view for a closing PHP tag without the > character?

Comment: "Cakephp 2.3, so there are about 3.7 million files that get loaded" => Actually, the cake core is clean. The error is on your end - in your (app) code somewhere.